# Javascript variable evaluation

Tags: javascript, variables

```
(function(){

   var commentList = $("#commentList");

});
```

Given the context above will `commentList`  get evaluated every time use the variable?

Comment: If you ask whether `$("#commentList")` will be executed every time you access `commentList`, then no. Unfortunately your example is not very clear... the surrounding function is not and can never be executed. Please provide a better example (and clarify your question).

Comment: Given what context? You are declaring an anonymous function, which is never invoked, nor is a reference stored to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be evaluated afresh each time the function is called.

Once inside the function, it will be evaluated once, not each time the var is called.

Answer (score 2):

no, that variable will store a reference to it, so every time you use `commentList` you won't also re-evaluate `$("#commentList")` (except for the first assignment, of course)

Answer (score 2):

No. You can easily check it

```
<script>
$(function(){

   var commentList = $("#commentList");
   console.log(commentList);
   $('#commentList').html('');
   console.log(commentList);

});
</script>

<div id="commentList">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is evaluated once, when the assignment takes place.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PxRXF/